# how to send verification code from asp.net website to mobile

Tags: asp.net

i want to send the verification code  when user registered in asp.net website to his mobile but i do not know anything about how i can do it
please can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You'd need an SMS gateway, such as [Esendex](http://www.esendex.co.uk/) (which I've used) or [Intellisoftware's SMS Gateway](http://www.intellisoftware.co.uk/sms-gateway/dotnet-component/) (which I haven't).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an SMS gateway for this task at all. Simply email the cell phone, it'll come across as an SMS. See the article here http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/email-to-sms/ for how to email a cell phone, this article tells you how to send email from asp.net https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121616/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072606-1.aspx